# Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?) Error testing api-platform endpoint

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a Product entity, related to another User entity with a relation manyToOne

```
class Product implements AuthoredEntityInterface
{
/**
* @ORM\Id()
* @ORM\GeneratedValue()
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="products")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $user;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
private $name;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="double")
*/
private $price;

//various getters and setters

}
```

The AuthoredEntityInterface helps to set the user to the current logged in user. when I make an api call to /api/products (I use postman) passing a json like this:

```
{
    "name": "my product",
    "price": 10
}
```

This works and a new record is created. The problem is with unit tests. I make a call like this:

```
$headers = [
        'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/ld+json',
        'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/ld+json'
    ];
$postData = [
    'name' => 'my product',
    'price' => 10
];
$client = $this->makeClient();
    $client->request('POST', '/api/products', [], [], $headers, json_encode($postData));
```

I get this error: 
    **Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?)**

Now the only IRI is referring to should be user, that as mentioned is auto-generated inside the class.

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

To populate the user field

Method in Product

```
public function setUser(UserInterface $user): AuthoredEntityInterface
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

Then I use an event subscriber:

```
class AuthoredEntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
/** @var TokenStorageInterface */
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::VIEW => ['getAuthenticatedUser', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE]
    ];
}

public function getAuthenticatedUser(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getControllerResult();
    $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

    /** @var UserInterface $user */
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if((!$entity instanceof AuthoredEntityInterface) || Request::METHOD_POST != $method) {
        return;
    }

    $entity->setUser($user);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have an ID attribute on User ? As well as getter/Setter on product and user ?

Comment: I have getters on both entities, setters aren't needed 'cause the field is auto increment (@ORM\GeneratedValue())

Answer (score 0):

You must encode your `$postData` into content type you want, eg. JSON, and encoded data must be passed into `$client->request()`

Comment: Sorry I missed a bit, $postData is already json encoded. I updated the question.

Comment: How do you fill User into your Product? Can you show the part of code?

Comment: @user3174311 Well, it looks good, so what about token, are you sure its right? Is it `$user` variable filled in getAuthenticatedUser() call?

Comment: Have you tried logging `$user` in `AuthoredEntitySubscriber` or in `function setUser`. Are you running tests on other environments? If so, do they contains the same user data?

Comment: @ThomasVangelooven I can't log $user the AuthoredEntitySubscriber is not executed, the error is exactly when I run the request. I setup the application to run tests on an instance of sqlite, data is correctly set using fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're encountering the same error I had awhile back, authentication credentials shouldn't be passed in the request head, it should be passed via the client.

Sample:

```
$credentials = array(
    'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
);

$client = $this->makeClient($credentials);
```

Also make sure that `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` is the correct name that you need to be using. Alot of times it's just Authorization.

To recap there's request headers and client headers. Make sure you're setting auth in client headers.

Comment: makeClient is expected to receive an array with username and password, or nothing. Here I am authenticating using a bearer token. Anyway, the problem is not with authentication: for some reason I don't know yet my AuthoredEntitySubscriber is not triggered ONLY when i use phpunit/Liip.

Comment: @user3174311 I concur, just confirmed on my stack, that you indeed need header `Authorization` to send the bearer token, as suggested by Lulceltech. It makes sense for no user to be loaded when no token is found.